# Convert to my time zone - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Could somebody give me a help?

I have a source data where it is in another server in another country, when I get it to my B.I Staging area, I want to convert it to my time zone, but my SQL Server versions is 2014.

I can't use AT TIME ZONE SQL Server function.
Is there any other way to do this without fixing a hard coded value like below?

The below result doesn't solve my problem, because its hard coded values:

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET (DATETIMEFIELD, '-03:00')
SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(DATETIMEFIELD,'-03:00')
```

Ps: Not forgetting about DAYLIGHT SAVING

Comment: What datatype is the original data? `datetime`/`datetime2` or are you making use of `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: @Larnu the souce data is a datetime column

Comment: I assume, due to your mention of Daylightsavings, that either you, or the source don't use Daylight Savings, or they are on separate days?

Comment: Do you have the time zone information stored anywhere? DATETIME does not store it and it is treated as local time (server time zone)

Comment: I just want to convert all the values from the source to my time zone, and when that source date be equal to my target, I’d like to get it converted as my daylight saving. The source is a datetime

Comment: @EvertonGomes BTW *both* functions work and return a datetimeoffset value. The first treats the `datetime` input as UTC and returns the equivalent time in the new timezone. The second appends the offset to the inpu. What does `doesn't solve my problem` mean? What was the input value and what the expected result?

Comment: @Tanner no reason to do this, if you use `datetimeoffset`. No need to worry what "my time zone" means in this case

Comment: I must agree with @PanagiotisKanavos - What is the input and your expected result?

Comment: @EvertonGomes don't repeat the question in the comments. Post actual examples. The functions work. Why do you think they don't? What are the input values and what are the output? BTW, the *offset* doesn't adjust itself for summer time. A lot of timezones have the same offset but use different DST times. You have to know the correct *offset* in advance.

Comment: @EvertonGomes another option is to actually store the IANA timezone name in a separate field and use a library like NodaTime to convert the values. This way you won't have to worry about providing the correct offset, the IANA database contains the appropriate rules for every date and timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample data, this is very much a stab in the dark, that at least tries to explain it. Note, that this isn't fool proof. For example, when the clocks go **back** then the times 01:00:00 - 01:59:59 will occur twice. These times will **always** be assumed to be **before** DST, regardless of if they really were.

Anyway, firstly I created a small table with the dates that DST occurred both in the UK (GMT: UTC + 0) and in Eastern America (EST: UTC - 5).

Then, I created a query as below, using that data.

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--SAmple Daylight Savings Table
CREATE TABLE DaylightSaving (Timezone char(3),
                             ClocksChangeDate datetime,
                             Change smallint,
                             UTCDiff smallint);
--Dates for UK
INSERT INTO DaylightSaving
VALUES ('GMT','20170326 02:00:00',1,0),
       ('GMT','20171029 02:00:00',0,0),
       ('GMT','20180325 02:00:00',1,0),
       ('GMT','20181028 02:00:00',0,0),
       ('GMT','20190331 02:00:00',1,0),
       ('GMT','20191027 02:00:00',0,0);

--Dates for Eastern America
INSERT INTO DaylightSaving
VALUES ('EST','20170312',1,-5),
       ('EST','20171105',0,-5),
       ('EST','20180311',1,-5),
       ('EST','20181104',0,-5),
       ('EST','20190310',1,-5),
       ('EST','20191103',0,-5);
GO
--Made up sample data

CREATE TABLE SampleData (DateAndTime datetime, Timezone char(3));

INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES ('20180123 12:28:00.000','EST'),
       ('20180523 19:58:00.000','EST'),
       ('20181101 07:19:00.000','EST'),
       ('20190330 20:50:00.000','EST'),
       ('20190330 21:05:00.000','EST');
GO

SELECT DateAndTime AS ESTTime,
       DATEADD(HOUR, 5 + DT.Change - ST.Change, DateAndTime) AS GMTTime,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, DateAndTime, DATEADD(HOUR, DT.UTCDiff - ST.UTCDiff + DT.Change - ST.Change, DateAndTime)) AS TimeZoneDifference,
       ST.ClocksChangeDate, DT.ClocksChangeDate
FROM SampleData SD
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                  FROM DaylightSaving sq
                  WHERE sq.ClocksChangeDate <= SD.DateAndTime
                    AND Timezone = SD.Timezone
                  ORDER BY sq.ClocksChangeDate DESC) ST
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                  FROM DaylightSaving sq
                  WHERE sq.ClocksChangeDate <= DATEADD(HOUR, sq.UTCDiff - ST.UTCDiff,SD.DateAndTime)
                    AND sq.Timezone = 'GMT' --your destination Timezone
                  ORDER BY sq.ClocksChangeDate DESC) DT;


GO

DROP TABLE DaylightSaving;
DROP TABLE SampleData;
```

*Edit: Note that that the difference between the 2 zones was hard coded (I have a `DATEADD` with a hard coded value of `5`), as this is an example. You will need to extrapolate this for your own system, but as we have no concept of what that looks like, you'll need to do that work.*

*Edit 2:Felt like adding the timezone diffs in. Only hard coded value now is the value of the local timezone (`'GMT'` in this case in the second `CROSS APPLY`)*

As several people have said, `datetime` has no concept of timezones. If this is paramount to your data, then don't use `datetime`, use `datetimeoffset`. That stores the UTC +/- value as part of the value; making things like this trivial.